# Simplify iterative if / else if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, iteration

I've written some JavaScript which basically make different pixels visible, depending on the time. I've written the code (for the seconds at least), and it's working fine, but I'm having trouble simplifying it so I don't have to type out the (almost) same code over and over.

Here is an example of my code :

```
    var getTime = function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var mins = date.getMinutes();
            var secs = date.getSeconds();

            if (secs==0) {
                for (var s=1; s < 60; s++) {
                    $("#s" + s).removeClass('display');
                };
            } else if (secs == 1) {
                for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
                    $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
                };
            } else if (secs == 2) {
                for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
                    $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
                };
            } else if (secs == 3) {
                for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
                    $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
                };
            .........(cont.)
            } else if (secs == 59) {
                for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
                    $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Why do you have the `if` statements at all? Each one (except the first) does the **exact** same thing

Comment: Add a same class to all of your elements, for example `'sec'`, and store them once and for all : `var $secs = $('.sec');` Then use `$secs[s].addClass(...`. Can't beleive no ones actually noticed such a huge performance waste.

Comment: @Virus721 HA! I can't believe I didn't think of that either. Still, that requires modifying the HTML, which may or may not be possible. I'd definitely add an answer with that though

Comment: I can modify the HTML no problem, would you mind elaborating in an answer, I'm still a beginner and it would really help me understand better.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to display the `#s` based on the number of second. The simple solution is to clear all and set display again.

```
var getTime = function() {
   var date = new Date();
   var hours = date.getHours();
   var mins = date.getMinutes();
   var secs = date.getSeconds();

   //Hide all ids starting with 's'
   $('[id^=s]').removeClass('display');

   for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
       $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

(updated to make sure the behavior is correct even if we missed a tick)

```
var getTime = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();
    var secs = date.getSeconds();

    for (var s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
      var elements = $("#s" + s);
      elements.removeClass('display');
      if (s <= secs) {
          elements.addClass('display');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something since don't get why you have 59 `else` conditions that looks the same

```
var getTime = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();
    var secs = date.getSeconds();

    if (secs==0)
        for (var s=1; s < 60; s++)
            $("#s" + s).removeClass('display');
    else
        for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++)
            $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is always the same for secs over 0

```
if (secs < 1) {

    for (var s=1; s < 60; s++) {
        $("#s" + s).removeClass('display');
    };


} else {

    for (var s=1; s < (secs+1); s++) {
        $("#s" + s).addClass('display');
    };


}
```